# Correct HTTP error code for MediaTypeFormatter failure

Tags: http, http-error, httpexception

We have written a custom media type formatter.  When we find that we cannot deserialise the input then we want to throw an error.  I'd like to return an HTTP error code to the user that was making the PUT/POST request, but I am not sure what is the correct error code to return. 
Any ideas?

Comment: 400 (Bad Request), 415 (Unsupported Media Type, or 422 (Unprocessable Entity) seem suitable.

Comment: Thanks, kind of on the lines that I was thinking.  I don't think that we'll use 415 as the media type in the Accept header is correct, but as we can't deserialise that then I guess we'll go with 400